# Elementary OS Updates And Security

Tags: security

I am very, very new to Linux. I am taken aback at how upon installing elementaryOS I was immediately hit with a series of "updates" to various functionalities.

How do I know these updates are safe? Or even what they did to my machine? How do I know there wasn't a MIM attack, or if my machine has been compromised with a keylogger or something? Is there a way to check whatever's going on my machine against some kind of "official" version?

Sorry if this is an idiot question, I am new to all of this but I hear you can do that with opensource stuff?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a dumb question. If the updates were done through the App Store, it would be fine. You could also update using the command line console

(this is the command)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Updates are provided by the repositories available on your system. The safety depends on multiple factors, a proper summary can be found here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for